# In Dart what is the generated name for a setter method?

Tags: dart, setter, dart-mirrors

If I have a class with a setter defined, how do I reference then generated method as a function from an instance of that class. The spec sort of suggests it would be the id of the variable + '=" (seems daft), but this doesn't parse.

So for example:

```dart
class Bar {

  set foo(int value) {
  //whatever
  }
}

typedef F(int value);

void main() {
  F f = new Bar().foo=; //Fails, but what should this be??
  f(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setter is named `foo=` but this is not something you can reference in the way you want. Even looking at dart:mirrors the MethodMirror (the mirror for object methods including setters) has no way of invoking it. You could easily rewrite this as:

```dart
class Bar {

  set foo(int value) {
  //whatever
  }
}

typedef F(int value);

void main() {
  Bar b = new Bar();
  F f = (int value) => b.foo = value;
  f(5);
}
```

Comment: You can invoke a setter with mirrors with MethodMirror.invoke(). I think you have to use the "set:" prefix still to get the mirror.

Comment: Hey Justin, looking at: http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/lib/mirrors/mirrors.dart?r=10918 I don't see an invoke method in MethodMirror. There is one in ObjectMirror but it has a very different signature than F(int value) and thus could not be assigned to an F.

Comment: Oops, you're right. It's on ObjectMirror and it looks like there's setField() now too. It won't have the signature f(int v) because it has to handle any method invocation, so it works more like noSuchMethod().

Also, you can't closurize methods through the mirror system. That would be awesome though. Maybe if InstanceMirror.hasReflectee is true it could let you capture members.

Comment: Hmmm! Seems disappointing that getter and setters aren't just syntactic sugar for methods that can be used in this way. But I guess I see the problem - these methods would need to be generated for instance variables too, as the caller should be unaware of whether variable access was by backed by a setters/getters. Anyway, thx for the help.